# roundcube/managesieve sends vacation replies only to local users

Tags: postfix, sieve

I've had a round cube / postfix setup with os x server (10.8) for some time working. Today we discovered that the vacation filter is only sending messages to local users. It was working some time ago, so I guess an update broke something. I've reinstalled roundcube but still only local users get vacations responses.

I guess it must be a mail routing but I can't figure out what is wrong. Any ideas would be appreciated.

This is the log of a message sent from myself@outside.example.net to user@example.com

```
macmini.example.com postfix/qmgr[5115]: 3508123A2110: from=<myself@outside.example.net>, size=2674, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
macmini.example.com postfix/smtpd[5152]: disconnect from mxout-027-ewr.mailhop.org[216.146.33.27]
macmini.example.com postfix/smtpd[5118]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
macmini.example.com postfix/smtpd[5118]: 3FB9A23A2119: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
macmini.example.com postfix/cleanup[5120]: 3FB9A23A2119: message-id=<CAGgjO8Pv4UZ+QmDOgJdo8V5MZptiRTP25c0w2bnwZieNyrnUMQ@mail.gmail.com>
macmini.example.com postfix/smtpd[5118]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
macmini.example.com postfix/qmgr[5115]: 3FB9A23A2119: from=<myself@outside.example.net>, size=3101, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
macmini.example.com postfix/smtp[5116]: 3508123A2110: to=<user@example.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=1.2, delays=1.1/0/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 3FB9A23A2119)
macmini.example.com postfix/qmgr[5115]: 3508123A2110: removed
macmini.example.com postfix/pickup[5114]: 4A8E123A211C: uid=214 from=<>
macmini.example.com postfix/cleanup[5120]: 4A8E123A211C: message-id=<dovecot-sieve-1419283881-289928-0@macmini.example.com>
macmini.example.com postfix/qmgr[5115]: 4A8E123A211C: from=<>, size=659, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
macmini.example.com postfix/pipe[5122]: 3FB9A23A2119: to=<user@example.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.05, delays=0/0/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
macmini.example.com postfix/qmgr[5115]: 3FB9A23A2119: removed
macmini.example.com postfix/smtpd[5118]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
macmini.example.com postfix/smtpd[5118]: 58C3C23A2129: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
macmini.example.com postfix/cleanup[5120]: 58C3C23A2129: message-id=<dovecot-sieve-1419283881-289928-0@macmini.example.com>
macmini.example.com postfix/qmgr[5115]: 58C3C23A2129: from=<>, size=1088, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
macmini.example.com postfix/smtp[5116]: 4A8E123A211C: to=<myself@outside.example.net>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=0.08, delays=0/0/0/0.07, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 58C3C23A2129)
macmini.example.com postfix/qmgr[5115]: 4A8E123A211C: removed
```

This is the rule that roundcube/managesieve generated

```
require ["vacation"];
# rule:[out 2]
if true
{
   vacation :days 1 :addresses ["user@example.com"] :subject "not here" "out of office";
}
```

Now I see that my mail relay is bouncing the reply because it is sent from <> (note that this is not obscured, it is empty

```
macmini.example.com postfix/smtp[5173]: 58C3C23A2129: to=<myself@outside.example.net>, relay=smtpcorp.com[216.22.15.247]:25, delay=2.1, delays=1/0.02/0.9/0.16, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host smtpcorp.com[216.22.15.247] said: 550-MDR refused, to send MAIL FROM: <> use both IP-address and password 550 xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/32 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Comment: The message delivery hasn't finished at this stake. Can you run command `grep 58C3C23A2129 maillog`? It will tell you the current status of delivery...

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks. I changed the policies and now the replies are going out.Is there a way to avoid the from=<> and have it actually insert the sender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This maillog line

```
macmini.example.com postfix/smtp[5173]: 58C3C23A2129: to=<myself@outside.example.net>, relay=smtpcorp.com[216.22.15.247]:25, delay=2.1, delays=1/0.02/0.9/0.16, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host smtpcorp.com[216.22.15.247] said: 550-MDR refused, to send MAIL FROM: <> use both IP-address and password 550 xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/32 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Indicated that your SMTP upstream was refused to relay your email. Looks like modifying policy was working solution for you.

> Is there a way to avoid the from=<> and have it actually insert the sender?

[RFC 5230](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5230.txt) section 4.3 says that it is possible to use custom sender when send out vacation. Just specify `:from "user@example.com"` in the rule. For example

```
vacation :days 1 :from "user@example.com" :addresses ["user@example.com"] :subject "not here" "out of office";
```

I'm not familiar with roundcube, so I can't tell you if plugin managesieve has ability to set the sender.

[Reference(s)](http://www.dovecot.org/pipermail/dovecot/2011-August/130439.html)